# Why is connectCallback() not bound to the same this as the constructor with custom elements v1?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-component, custom-element

Could somebody with a better knowledge of custom elements explain why the connectedCallback is bound to this in Chrome, but not in Safari, IE and FF?

```
"use strict";


class XChat extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._chats = null;
    console.log(this._chats); // null
  }

  connectedCallback() {

    console.log(this._chats); // undefined in safari, IE, FF, null in chrome
  }

}
customElements.define('x-chat', XChat);
```

and in webpack entry file:

```
import 'document-register-element';
import './components/x-chat/index.html';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: read the docs, and use the ceveat. The constructor should look like this:

```
constructor(self) {
    self = super(self);
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a polyfill to use custom elements v1 with Safari, IE or FF.

You can use [document-register-element](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element) v1.4:

```
bower install document-register-element
```

Or instead you can use [webcomponentsjs v1](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/tree/v1) (release candidate):

```
bower install webcomponentsjs#v1
```

With that you'll get consistent results between Chrome and polyfilled (`undefined` for `constructor()` and `null` for `connectedCallback()`)

Comment: I edited my question. To be clear: I am using the document-register-element polyfill.